# How do I pass an object from an azure data factory lookup to a notebook so I can use the object/json within a python script

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am using Azure Data Factory for the first time.

I have a lookup with a source dataset that is a table from azure table storage

I have a notebook which has a Base Parameter called 'input' with the value:

```
@activity('Lookup1').output
```

The notebook path refers to a python script that does nothing yet.

When I try and debug the pipeline I get and error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2105",
    "message": "The value type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx]]', in key 'input' is not expected type 'System.String'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Notebook1"
}
```

I would like to be able to use the json object in the python script. Do I have to change the Base Parameter some way to serialise the object?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert it to a string using @string:
https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#conversion-functions

This should work: @string(activity('Lookup1').output)

This converts the object to a json string, you can probably parse that in your notebook.

Comment: when I try and use the parameter ('input') in the python it says it isn't defined