# Azure Data Factory - How to return JSON from azure function as an argument and pass it to Databricks service?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, databricks

I'm building pipline using azure functions and databricks service.

In my function I'm returning JSON fetched from external api. It works and function returns it as a call result. I need to use this JSON within my databricks service -> Clear it and save it to sql (I know how to do this part).

I want to avoid creation of binary json file and prefer to pass function's result straight to databricks. Is there any way to do that?

I thought about calling my azure function within databricks using python but I'm not sure it is the way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can now pass values back to ADF from a notebook.
Though there is a size limit, so if you are passing dataset of larger than 2MB then rather write it on storage, and consume it directly with Azure Functions. You can pass the file path/ reference to ADF --> Azure Functions.

Need to convert it as a string

```
@string(activity('Lookup1').output)
```

Below links will provide you the complete information about the ADF to Azure Function.

[Using String Value in notebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#conversion-functions)

[Databricks output to azure function.](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/17878/can-we-pass-databricks-output-to-azure-function-bo.html)

Also check the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55952551) for related information.